# Encountering a TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror

This is my original code, which runs fine on Python:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Truncating the file.     Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write("%s \n%s \n%s \n") % (line1, line2, line3)

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

I then attempted to clean up the repetition:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Truncating the file.     Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write("%s \n%s \n%s \n") % (line1, line2, line3)

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

For some reason the new code does not completely run, it gets to line 27 and then returns

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Any idea on how I can correct this issue?

I am very new to coding in general and I am learning to code in Python 2.6, using Zed Shaw's "Learning Code the Hard Way", so any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Typo? You closed off the `write()` method.

Comment: Hi Peter. Your last line is a bit concerning. You are just starting to learn Python, why are you using 2.6?

Comment: Also, the "first" and "second" code look to be the exact same...

Comment: `target.write("%s \n%s \n%s \n" % (line1, line2, line3))`

Comment: If you are new to Python, why are you starting with Python 2? The [Stack Overflow Python community](http://sopython.com) overwhelmingly [recommends](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) starting with Python 3, as does [python.org itself](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3). Version 3 is the present and future of the language, while 2 is the past. In learning 2 first, you'll pick up many bad habits that will need to be corrected when you learn 3 (which you'll need to do eventually), so it's much better to start with 3 first, then learn the differences in 2 later.

Comment: *Learn Python the Hard Way* is [just awful](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). We ***strongly*** recommend using a different tutorial, and using Python 3, as I indicated above.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or book that you recommend using for someone who is brand new to coding in Python?

Comment: @Peter there is the official Python 3 tutorial; plenty of resources linked at https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntroductoryBooks for example; some of them have free E-books!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your line `target.write("%s \n%s \n%s \n") % (line1, line2, line3)` is the problem.

You've closed off the `write` function call before doing the variable substitutions. So the variables line1, line2, and line3 are not being inserted into the %s's. Therefore you've got a bunch of `None`'s getting written instead which is causing the error.

Change it to look like this:

```
target.write("%s \n%s \n%s \n" % (line1, line2, line3))
```

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is a string operator; you are trying to use it with the return value of `target.write()`.

```
target.write("%s \n%s \n%s \n" % (line1, line2, line3))
```

If you are just starting, I encourage you to switch to Python 3.5 and the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) syntax. This way, you won't have problems with the premature closure of parentheses:

```
target.write("{0} \n{1} \n{2} \n".format(line1, line2, line3))
```

Version 3.6 is currently in development and starting beta testing, and it will have a much more natural syntax for building this kind of string called [f strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
target.write(f'{line1}\n{line2}\n{line3}\n')
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to recommend f strings? 3.6 only just released beta 1, so it's definitely not production-ready yet. I would suggest 3.5 and using the `.format()` syntax...

Comment: My bad; I didn't realize 3.6 was only a beta release yet.